# Initialize 2D list

Tags: python

The follow codes didn't behave like I expected. Is this an incorrect way of initializing a 2D list filled with 0?

```
matrix = [[0] * 4] * 4
for row in matrix:
    print(row)
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]


matrix[0][0] = 1
for row in matrix:
    print(row)
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: What did you want it to look like? Just an 2D array of 0's?

Comment: @burntchowmein yes

Comment: @Derek O has the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Use `matrix = [[0 for i in range(4)] for j in range(4)]` instead of `matrix = [[0] * 4] * 4`.

```
matrix = [[0 for i in range(4)] for j in range(4)]
matrix[0][0] = 1
for row in matrix:
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the matrix is composed of a copy of the list [0,0,0,0].

This should work:

```
matrix = [[0 for i in range(4)] for j in range(4)]
matrix[0][0] = 1
```

Comment: Is there a shorter way of doing this for a list of size n x n?

Comment: What if there are a 1000 rows? This solution is very naive.

Comment: Yeah I agree that my original answer was silly so I updated it. I mainly wanted to address the dangers of initializing a list with copies.

Answer (score 1):

I actually ran into this problem a while ago! No, this isn't the correct way, at least for what you're expecting to happen.

The problem is that when you initialise this list, you create a list of *references* back to the first item, so when you modify it, you modify all of them, because in reality they all point to the same object in memory.

Instead of that you can do something like this:

```py
x = 4
y = 4
matrix = [[0]*x for _ in range(y)]
```

With a result of:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Then `matrix[0][0] = 1` only sets the first element of the first list to 1.

You can extend this into 3D and beyond by simply adding a new layer of for __ in range(z) on the end and and wrapping it in more square brackets.

Comment: This does not fully answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for suggested edit Derek O, merged with my edit

Comment: You should also show the modification the value and it's result for the answer to be complete.

Comment: Yes, sorry I only saw the suggested edit after I'd finished being sarcastic, all fixed now I believe!

Comment: You may also keep in mind that use of excessive sarcasm _could_ lead to a temporary ban if many people report your comment as rude. https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Answer (score 0):

In the general case you can make something like [`numpy.full`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) (but for lists instead of arrays):

```
def full(shape, fill_value=0):
    if len(shape) > 1:
        return [full(shape[1:], fill_value) for _ in range(shape[0])]
    else:
        return [fill_value] * shape[0]

matrix = full((4, 4), 0)
```